# How to have different update values according to the conditions met

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

```
const questionSchema = new Schema({
    isAnonymous: Boolean,
    whoAsked: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
    user: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
    content: String, 
    isAnswered: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    answer: String,
    likes: {
        byWho: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
        count: {type: Number, default: 0}
    }
```

I would like to know if I can have similar effect to if condition where I can set different values according to a field according to if the outcome of a query is true or false

I know It can be done by just retrieving object from db and performing the checks but I was wondering if it can be done by only mongo
Similar to the example below

```
if( userId in likes.byWho){
    likes.count--;
    remove userId from likes.byWho;
}else{ 
    likes.count++;
    push userId into likes.byWho;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MongoDB 4.2 or newer, you can use the pipeline form of update to make use of the [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#cond-aggregation) aggregation expression

```
db.questions.update({},
  [
    {$set:{ 
          "likes.byWho":{$cond:{
                if: {$in:[userId, "$likes.byWho"]},
                then: {$setDifference:["$likes.byWho",[userId]]},
                else: {$concatArrays:["$likes.byWho",[userId]]}
          }}
    }},
    {$set:{"likes.count":{$size:"$likes.byWho"}}}
  ] 
)
```